# Disable a button in the fragment/xml file when "ok" is clicked on the alertdialog

Tags: android

How to disable a button for like 5 - 10 secs after I click the positive button in AlertDialog.

e.g. when I clicked the button in the fragment an AlertDialog will popup then when I click the OK button the button in the fragment will be disabled for a time.

```
public class LockDialog extends DialogFragment {
  @Override
  public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
      builder.setTitle("Title");
      builder.setMessage("LOCK");
     builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //HERE WHEN I CLICK OK THE BUTTON IN THE XML FILE WILL BE DISABLED
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "LOCK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    return builder.create();
}
}
```

XML:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start"
    android:id="@+id/btnStart"
    android:layout_below="@+id/space"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#125688"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:onClick="onStart" />
```

Comment: none, bec. I cant even declare the button in the "onCreateDialog" Still searching.

Comment: Where is the button that you want to disable? In the AlertDialog? In the parent layout of the AlertDialog?

Comment: In the parent layout of the AlertDialog, yeah

Comment: Provide your xml and java file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVE THE PROBLEM ( FOR THE FELLOW COMRADE)

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final ImageButton aw = (ImageButton)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnLock);
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Lock");
    builder.setMessage("MESSAGE");
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "LOCKING", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            aw.setEnabled(false);

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                aw.setEnabled(true);
                }
            },5000);
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    return builder.create();
  }
}
```

TY **Hitesh Sahu** FOR THE HELP

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this will disable button with id button 1 for 5 seconds

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Test");

            final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);

            builder.setView(input);

            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Disabled" + input.getText().toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    findViewById(R.id.button1).setEnabled(false);

                    Handler handler = new Handler();

                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Enabled" + input.getText().toString(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            findViewById(R.id.button1).setEnabled(true);

                        }
                    }, 5000);

                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            // This should I want.?!
                            dialog.cancel();

                        }
                    });

            alertDialog = builder.show();
```

Comment: you need to find your button in fragment   

using getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnStart)  or getView().findViewById(R.id.btnStart);